# Is this a static build?

Tags: bash, cmake, compilation, static-libraries, cross-compiling

Firstly, forgive me for my ignorance on this topic - I'm new to compiling as a whole and far from a programmer, and I'm trying to understand the concept of static vs shared builds/libraries.

I've adapted the guide [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) to cross-compile the x265 project from source using a MinGW-W64 toolchain to run on Windows. I'm trying to make it a static build, but when I do:

```
cd /ffmpeg_sources && if /cd x265 2> /dev/null; then hg pull && hg update && cd ..; else hg clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265; fi &&
cd x265/build/linux && PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" \
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local" -DENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static" ../../source \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="/ffmpeg_sources/x265/build/msys/toolchain-x86_64-w64-mingw32.cmake" &&
make -j$(nproc) &&
make install
```

...it creates the resulting files:

> -- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libx265.a
>   -- Installing: /usr/local/include/x265.h
>   -- Installing: /usr/local/include/x265_config.h
>   -- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/x265.pc
>   -- Installing: /usr/local/bin/x265.exe

Aside from the `.exe` file, there are at least three other files included as part of the installation, two of which are libraries, and I'm assuming they're there because they're relied on by the executable. However, it's always been my impression that "static" = portable, which having a few less files doesn't seem to satisfy.

Is this what is intended when creating a static build - that instead of relying on `.so` or `.dll` files, it will rely on just the `.a` and `.h` files? Or am I simply misunderstanding the Cmake switches I'm using and can this build be made even more static?

Comment: `.h` is a source file, the final program doesn't need it to *run*, only the compiler needs it to compile.  `.dlls` are dynamic/shared libraries on windows. `.a` are static libraries on Linux. check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/174356/745311) it could be helpful.

Comment: @Accountantم But if the executable doesn't need `.h` files to run, why is it created and moved by `make install` *after* compilation of the package? Also doesn't the requirement of `.a`/`.h` or `.lib` libraries mean that static libraries, whether on Linux or Windows, are just as portable as shared libraries are? Both of them still have to be distributed together, no?

Comment: the `.h` files are created here mostly because when you create a library to be used by others (e.g curl) you create it's interface as `.h` files, so when I use your library (static or shared) in my program, I include your `.h` file which has the declarations of the functions I will use from your library in my program.

Comment: *"are just as portable as shared libraries are"*... What do you mean by portability here ?

Comment: @Accountantم So hypothetically speaking, if I didn't intend to do any further compilation and just wanted to use the x265 CLI I could delete the .h files if I wanted? By portable I mean a program (in this case x265.exe) that compiles into just the one executable so it doesn't need to be distributed with any other libraries to be used. This is what I've always understood the compiling of a static program to mean.

Comment: Yes you can delete the `.h` files if you only are going to *use/run* the x265.exe CLI program. `.h` files only needed by the compiler(preprocessor) at the compile time.

Comment: When you use a static library(call a function that is defined in it) in your code, the linker will **COPY** the binary code from the static library into your final single executable(that is why it is called "static" because when the author of static library changes the code of the library, it can't be changed in the executable file that was compiled with old library without recompiling with new library), ...

Comment: .....but if it is a dynamic library, the linker will **NOT COPY** the code of the library instead it will create a table in the final executable that the OS will fill when it loads the executable *AND* the dynamic library to run the final executable. You need `.h` files to use BOTH static and dynamic libraries in your code (again only at compile time not run time).

Comment: check this [article](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/all-about-static-libraries-in-c-cea57990c495), I found it simple and clear

Comment: @Accountantم Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its [landing page](http://x265.org/) says:

> x265 is a H.265 / HEVC video encoder application library, designed to encode video or images into an H.265 / HEVC encoded bitstream.

the x265 project primarily provides a *library* that developers can link with their applications
to provide them with x265, H.265/HEVC encoding functionality. Secondarily, it provides a [commandline tool, x265](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/x265/x265.1.en.html)
for H.265/HEVC encoding of an input file to an output file.

One would therefore expect the package installation to provide -

*The library*

> -- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libx265.a

Check.

*One or more header files enabling compilation of library clients*

> -- Installing: /usr/local/include/x265.h
>
> -- Installing: /usr/local/include/x265_config.h

Check.

*A* [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) *file to provide
developers with the package's compilation and linkage metadata.*

> -- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/x265.pc

Check.

*The commandline tool*

> -- Installing: /usr/local/bin/x265.exe

Check.

It would also be usual for a library package to offer a configuration
switch to select building of a shared/dynamic library - `libname.so` (Windows: `[lib]name.dll`)
- or a static library - `libname.a` (Windows: `[lib]name.(a|lib)`) - defaulting
to shared.

You have opted for a static build:

```
DENABLE_SHARED=OFF
```

and have accordingly got just the static library `libx265.a`. Your
commandline executable `x265.exe` has a *buildtime* dependency on that library
and its header files  - just as would any other application that requires
linkage with `libx265`. But since it has been linked with the *static* library
`libx265.a`, the executable, once built, physically incorporates all the parts of
`libx265.a` that it depends upon and has no *runtime* dependency on it; indeed,
runtime dependency on a [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) is categorically impossible.

Furthermore, since you specified:

```
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static"
```

The linkage of your executable was *fully* static, i.e. the linker will have been obliged to find and link a static, not shared, version of *every* library required by the linkage, not just `libx265`, and on the evidence posted it succeeded.

Bottom line: Your installation appears to have gone exactly as it should, and you have a fully static executable `x265.exe`.

Comment: Does the fact that the `.h` files are buildtime dependencies that "enable compilation of library clients", and the `.a` file is physically incorporated into the executable, mean that if I don't intend to do any further compilation they could hypothetically be deleted to deliver only the `.exe`? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Also I noticed you made no mention of the `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` option  in my command - does that mean this option is redundant here?

Comment: @Hashim Hi. Yes, if you only want your x265 executable you may delete the header files
(and pkg-config file). If you have linked against the
static library `libx265.a`, as you have, you may also delete it. I hadn't
actually noticed your `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` but it is in fact redundant
and ineffectual - I've checked. By itself it allows the shared - as well as the static - library to
be built, and the executable gets linked against the *shared* library, which
in that case becomes a *runtime* dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a .dll.a file and you don't specify linker flag `-static` then it might be a "shared" build and you'd have to distribute it with the .exe and a .dll.  Since there isn't you're probably safe, it'll link against the .a file, and just an .exe is needed for distro.  Best bet is to try it on another computer just in case, cheers!